# Vue JS unable to display to DOM the returned data of method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2, vue-component

Template html

```
<div class="item" v-for="n, index in teamRoster">
   <span> {{ getFantasyScore(n.personId) }} </span>
</div>
```

Method

```
getFantasyScore(playerId) {
    if(playerId) {
        axios.get(config.NBLAPI + config.API.PLAYERFANTASYSCORE + playerId)
        .then( (response) => {
            if( response.status == 200 ) {
                console.log(response.data.total)
                return response.data.total;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the returned data to DOM but it doesnt display anything. But when I try to console log the data is displays. How can I be able to display it. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you populating the `teamRoster` object / array? Might be easier to just pre-fetch the fantasy-score data at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, your `getFantasyScore` method doesn't return anything and even then, the data is asynchronous and not reactive.

I would create a component that loads the data on creation. Something like

```
Vue.component('fantasy-score', {
  template: '<span>{{score}}</span>',
  props: ['playerId'],
  data () {
    return { score: null }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get(config.NBLAPI + config.API.PLAYERFANTASYSCORE + this.playerId)
      .then(response => {
        this.score = response.data.total
      })
  }
})
```

and then in your template

```
<div class="item" v-for="n, index in teamRoster">
  <fantasy-score :player-id="n.personId"></fantasy-score>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use methods for AJAX results because they are async. You could retrieve the full `teamRoster` object and then add this to your `div`:

```
<div class="item" v-for="fantasyScore in teamRoster" v-if="teamRoster">
   <span> {{ fantasyScore }} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `getFantasyScoreByPerson` called and how is the `id` passed to it?

Comment: @Phil, fixed that!

Comment: Not really. Where does `this.id` come from? How does it get the `id` from `n.personId` in the repeater?

Comment: I simplified it. Didn't read the requirements carefully. Just as an alternative solution to yours, which is the preferred one, @Phil.